# Custom iPhone User Interface Component

Tags: iphone, user-interface, components, slider

Can anyone list custom iPhone UI Components?

I know about the Three20 components which are UI and framework.  Does anyone know of other similar libraries of UI components for the iPhone.

To be even more specific I am looking for a horizontal slider that you can flick and it will continue sliding.  Currently Apple has those big wheels (UIPicker) which you can flick and it will continue spinning.  I want something similar but horizontal. I know I can code this myself but I wanted to see if there was anything similar out there.

Cheers, John.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this

http://iphoneized.com/2009/11/18-mobile-frameworks-development-tools-creating-iphone-apps/

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm I know of one (it's not a picker though but rather a progress view).

[CustomProgressView](http://www.obsessivecode.com/projects/ocprogress/)

To be honest its rather average and i've seen others custom UI components out there and they all kinda are rough around the edges.

If you need a custom UI element for something specific, code it yourself. Otherwise I'd stick to using Apple's UI elements. Apple do actually do UI pretty well usually and if you start using custom UI elements you may have trouble submitting to the AppStore. Besides that imagine if all apps made custom iPhone sliders, picker controls, etc. I'd imagine the iPhone experience would get a bit sour and it's one of the reasons people like to use the iPhone so much...consistency.

Having said that I HAVE created my own custom progress view because UIProgressView didn't cut it:

[image]

I guess I'm contradicting myself but what I'm saying is only modify in very specific circumstances....like games or things where you *expect* non-standard elements.

Answer (score 2):

Graph component. Sweet and simple to use. Straighforward iPhone way: http://code.google.com/p/s7graphview/