# Good sources for custom controls for iphone development on the web?

Tags: iphone, controls

I've looked hard and have been unable to find good websites that have aggregated custom controls that have been submitted by users to be shared with everyone. Does such a repository exist?

I would hope something like this existed considering that iPhone developers seem to be using similar custom controls. In particular, I'm trying to do folder-like tabs on the iPhone (similar to how it is done on websites).

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843167/is-there-a-gallery-of-reusable-iphone-components-on-the-web and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340266/custom-iphone-user-interface-component

Comment: Oh sweet. Thanks Brad. I looked.. but I swear hard to find.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fairly new site for custom iOS and Mac OS X controls, Cocoa Controls.

http://cocoacontrols.com/

Answer (score 2):

joe answered good.

Here are the sites from were you can find reusable components

1) http://cocoacontrols.com/

2) http://open.iphonedev.com/

3) http://cocoaobjects.com/

Here is the twitter account where you can find popular reusable components on github about iPhone or iPad

4) https://twitter.com/#!/github_objc

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the graphic design elements like buttons and views?  If so, check out the Teehan+Lax iPhone PSD file:  http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/2009/06/18/iphone-gui-psd-30/

Comment: No. More like custom built (programmed) controls.

Answer (score 0):

One source I just found is by Joe Hewitt who made the Facebook iPhone app. He has a bunch of custom stuff he's opened sourced.

http://joehewitt.com/post/the-three20-project/